# Why is this simple app throwing this error?

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

Having tried all that I could, finally I resort here for some expert advice.

This can't be a complex problem for someone like you to solve. Quite sure it's an easy tackle for you!

The error pooping on the screen is as follows[image]

Following is the meta tag that the app has:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self';font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https:; style-src 'self' ; script-src 'self'">
```

Tried to find the favicon.ico, but couldn't find any.

My head is spinning now!

Looking forward for your help!

Thanks a TON!

Comment: why are you using `default-src 'none';`?? cant you use `self`?

Comment: Have you tried to add `http://* 'unsafe-inline'` after `img-src 'self'`?
You can add also the following `default-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'`
The final tag would look like:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self http://* 'unsafe-inline''; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' data: https:; style-src 'self' ; script-src 'self'">`

Comment: @fatalcoder524 Would it make a difference?

Comment: Definitely it could make a difference since full url for favicon.ico comes from http and that is blocked @Onthewaytosuccess

Comment: @juanmajmjr I'll update the one see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @juanmajmjr I'll try your suggestion and see how it goes

Comment: @juanmajmjr Your one isn't working as well! It gives the same error

Comment: Can you try the following?
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' http://localhost:5050 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">` @Onthewaytosuccess

Comment: @juanmajmjr I'll see and let you know how it goes for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223440/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-juanmajmjr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSP you shown does contain the img-src, so Chrome console warn means this CSP does not acts on the page, but on page does act some another CSP.

Looks like your app does issue a default CSP somewhere and this CSP does not contain img-src directive.

So you do have 2 CSPs at the same time, in this case acts more restrictive one.

Check the presence the second `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` tag (in the HTML code) or HTTP header Content Security Policy (in the dev tool).

Alternatively you could remove your:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self';font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https:; style-src 'self' ; script-src 'self'">
```

and to see that the same warns still presence in the Chrome console because of second CSP.

> 

**Updated:** after some researches it was found a [real reason of /favicon blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614336/why-do-i-get-the-default-src-none-content-security-policy-error-on-react-pw/64631888#64631888) for the above case.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self';font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https:; style-src 'self' ; script-src 'self'">
```

Seeing this code:

1. You have set `default-src 'none'` and overriding it with `img-src 'self' data: https:`.
2. But the protocol in use is `http`.

Comment: I really didn't get what you said there. What do I need to replace now?

Comment: You mentioned `img-src 'self' data: https:` but the protocol you are using is `http` @Onthewaytosuccess Check this https://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: https://content-security-policy.com/img-src/ @Onthewaytosuccess