# Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'"

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-redux, react-router, content-security-policy

Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

The site gets loaded at first but after doing a refresh it gives the above error. I have built my site using React.js in front-end and back-end is of Node.js. My site is deployed on heroku.

Edit 1:

Also getting below this in issues

Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources because their origin is not included in the content security policy header
The Content Security Policy (CSP) improves the security of your site by defining a list of trusted sources and instructs the browser to only execute or render resources from this list. Some resources on your site can't be accessed because their origin is not listed in the CSP.

To solve this, carefully check that all of the blocked resources listed below are trustworthy; if they are, include their sources in the content security policy of your site. You can set a policy as a HTTP header (recommended), or via an HTML  tag.

⚠️ Never add a source you don't trust to your site's Content Security Policy. If you don't trust the source, consider hosting resources on your own site instead.

1 directive
Resource                                Status   Directive  Source code
https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico  blocked  img-src

Edit 2:

Response Header

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-type, Accept, Authorization
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 148
Date: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 18:23:41 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur

Edit 3:

For me, I forgot to declare

const path = require("path");

in my server.js and that was causing the above problem

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Please add response headers in question

Comment: @Ravindra 

Response Header

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-type, Accept, Authorization
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 148
Date: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 18:23:41 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur

Comment: @OrAssayag  which part of code do u want me to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have status code `500 Internal Server Error Server`, but not `200 OK`. In this case NodeJS runs the [finalhandler](https://uni.edu.gt/eventos/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js) which publish the default CSP: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'` for security reasons.
`default-src 'none'` blocks all resourses include images.

I guess you have `/favicon.ico` blocked, browsers loads it by default from the web pages root `/`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614336/why-do-i-get-the-default-src-none-content-security-policy-error-on-react-pw) is a similar issue was solved.

You need to fix `500 Internal Server Error Server`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

But for me, the problem was that I forgot to declare const path = require("path"); in my server.js